# Tab gets displayed in next line with visible class

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a simple bootstrap breadcrumb:

```
    <ul class="breadcrumb" id="tree_form_selector">
      <li data-tabselector="allgemeine_angaben" class="active tabselector" >
        Allgemeine Angaben
      </li>
      <li data-tabselector="pflegezustand" class="tabselector">
        <a href="#" >Pflegezustand</a>
      </li>
      <li data-tabselector="blüte_und_ertrag" class="tabselector">
        <a href="#" >Blüte und Ertrag</a>
      </li>
      <!-- Wird nur bei computernn/nicht bei mobile gezeigt -->
      <li data-tabselector="qr_code" class="visible-md tabselector">
        <a href="#" >QR-Code</a>
      </li>
      <!-- Wird nur bei mobile gezeigt -->
      <li data-tabselector="camera" class="visible-xs tabselector">
        <a href="#" >Kamera</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

As you can see the tabs with the tabselectors `camera` and `qr_code` both have a visible class.

Because of that the tabs are **displayed in a new line**.

[image]

**How can I prevent this? Or how can I display them only on specific viewport-sizes?**Thanks

http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/13428/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to use the `visible-xs-inline` that way it won't brake the line because I think it defaults to block. Here is the code using the inline.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/13430/)

Detailed information here : [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities-classes)

Answer (score 1):

Because of li elements have display:inline-block. But if you just use visible-xs it will use display:block !important. Therefore they will get all row you should use `visible-xs-inline-block`.

```
    <ul class="breadcrumb" id="tree_form_selector">
      <li data-tabselector="allgemeine_angaben" class="active tabselector" >
        Allgemeine Angaben
      </li>
      <li data-tabselector="pflegezustand" class="tabselector">
        <a href="#" >Pflegezustand</a>
      </li>
      <li data-tabselector="blüte_und_ertrag" class="tabselector">
        <a href="#" >Blüte und Ertrag</a>
      </li>
      <!-- Wird nur bei computernn/nicht bei mobile gezeigt -->
      <li data-tabselector="qr_code" class="visible-md-inline-block tabselector">
        <a href="#" >QR-Code</a>
      </li>
      <!-- Wird nur bei mobile gezeigt -->
      <li data-tabselector="camera" class="visible-xs-inline-block tabselector">
        <a href="#" >Kamera</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

You can check code here http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/13429/

[Detail information](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities-classes)

Answer (score 0):

To show class only in mobile version you ca use responsive css:

```
.visible-xs{
 display: none;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 480px){
 .visible-xs{
  display: inline-block;
 }
}
```

But better creat you own class to prevent overriding of visible-xs.
hope, I understand you correctly.